# A JavaScript Code on web-page for Local time

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript. The codes below are, together, supposed to output local time on webpage, however, it is not working, the current time isn't showing, the web-page is blank. I need help, please. 
Thanks. 
Code source https://www.w3resource.com/JavaScript-exercises/JavaScript-basic-exercise-1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript current day and time</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>


var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDay();
  var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday ","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
  var hour = today.getHours();
  var minute = today.getMinutes();
  var second = today.getSeconds();
  var prepand = (hour >= 12)? " PM ":" AM ";
  hour = (hour >= 12)? hour - 12: hour;
  if (hour===0 && prepand===' PM ') 
  { 
  if (minute===0 && second===0)
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' Noon';
  } 
  else
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' PM';
  } 
  } 
  if (hour===0 && prepand===' AM ') 
  { 
  if (minute===0 && second===0)
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' Midnight';
  } 
  else
  { 
  hour=12;
  prepand=' AM';
  } 
  } 
console.log("Current Time : "+hour + prepand + " : " + minute + " : " + second);
```

Sorry, for the mistake in the HTML code. This is exactly the way it is presented in the link I provided. The caption on the link isn't same as mine here, but it has the info I needed.

Comment: What exactly does "it is not working" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but don't forget to *close* your `<meta>` tag.

Comment: I made it into a snippet and it seems to be working fine. What's the issue?

Comment: Oh... `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="currentTime.js">` that can't be right...

Comment: Also, the link you gave is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to put your JS inside a link tag. You should add it as a good practice at the end of your body, and in a SCRIPT tag like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="currentTime.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need more help. Regards

Some additional information:

[link tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp):  The  tag is used to link to external style sheets.

[script tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp): The  tag is used to define a client-side script (JavaScript).

Comment: Script field is normally in the HEAD.  They can be declared in the body and the browser will parse them, but they are supposed to be in HEAD.

Comment: They are not **supposed** to be in the head. There are valid reasons for placing script tags later in the content so they can load later and not prevent the content from loading.

Comment: https://faqs.skillcrush.com/article/176-where-should-js-script-tags-be-linked-in-html-documents - It is a best practice to put JavaScript <script> tags just before the closing </body> tag rather than in the <head> section of your HTML.

Comment: I have added the line <script src="currentTime.js"></script> as Richard Fazzi suggested, tho, it wasn't in the original code from the source. Despite that, the page is still not showing the time.

Comment: the time is shown on the console, not in the HTML, have you checked the console?

Comment: Thanks Richard Faazi, I just checked the console and it is there. Please, what command should i Use so it will show on the webpage? Thanks once again.

Comment: @Lovesome that's a different question. If you look around you'll find plenty of answers on the web.

Comment: I agree with Federico, you should check that on internet. but, you can add a div with ID "time" and in your JS add a line like `document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Current Time : " + hour + prepand + " : " + minute + " : " + second;` then you will get what you are looking for, but not in real time

Comment: Richard Fazzi, Thanks once again. It worked. I will do more research from here.